In Scheme, is there a way to print a human readable version of a continuation?
I'm trying to make a function in Scheme that asks the user for input to complete a continuation. As part of this, I want to print out the continuation so the user can see what will happen with their input.
For example, in Racket this might look like
(define (ask-user-input prompt)
  (call/cc (lambda (k)
             (displayln prompt)
             (displayln "Here is the current continuation:")
             (displayln k) ; <-- The line I need help with
             (k (read (current-input-port))))))

which could be used, for example, in the following function:
(define (guessing-game secret)
  (let ((number (ask-user-input "Guess a number.")))
    (cond ((< number secret)
           (displayln "Too low.")
           (guessing-game secret))
          ((> number secret)
           (displayln "Too High.")
           (guessing-game secret))
          (else
           (displayln "That's right!")))))

(guessing-game 50)

The problem is that when I print out the continuation, I just get an uninformative #<procedure>, not anything human readable. Is there a way to get a human readable display?
If I understand continuations in most Schemes correctly, they are ordinary procedures. Perhaps I'm asking the wrong question, and what I should really be asking is how I can recover human-readable code from the machine's representation of the procedure.
I'm not very particular on which Scheme I use. If this is something easily done in, for example, Guile Scheme, I would be happy to switch to that. I'm also not too particular on whether the "human-readable" representation uses the same variable names as the original code (and stuff like that). Decompiling a compiled procedure is acceptable. If it only works for delimited continuations, that's also fine (though I'd be surprised if it only works for delimited continuations but not full continuations).
To summarize: Is there a Scheme in which it is possible to print out continuations in a human-readable format?
Thanks!

What would that even look like?

What are you expecting, something like #<continuation that assigns to variable number in procedure guessing-game>? I don't think anything like that exists.

I'm expecting either (1) a quoted expression that when evaluated and applied to the user's value gives the result or (2) a sequence of instructions the computer will carry out after the user provides input.

for those wondering what it could look like, (+ 1 (* 2 (call/cc (lambda (k) (print k))))) could print something like (lambda (k) (+ 1 (* 2 k))) or just (+ 1 (* 2 __))
